# Trying to remove a class and add a class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues trying to resize my iframe. I want to be able to add and remove a class so that it can get wider then smaller. I can't even get adding a class to work for some reason. Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(
  $('#resize').onclick(function() {
    $('.frame_wrap').addclass('test');
  })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview_site">
  <div class="preview_wrap">
    <iframe class="frame_wrap" src="https://www.bdanzer.com"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="resize">Button</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fesye0mu/3/

Comment: Try using correct function name `addClass`. Case matters. Also, `onclick` should be `click`. You also have no anonymous function in document ready.

Comment: @Arg0n what do you mean by "have no anonymous function in document ready"?

Comment: See my answer for working solution and difference.

Comment: Did you look at the error(s) in your console? If you had, you'd have seen what the problem was.

Comment: @Bdanzer See http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/, http://api.jquery.com/click and http://api.jquery.com/addclass for more information

Comment: @Arg0n ahh ok thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a `function` to `$(document).ready()`.

`addclass` should be `addClass`, uppercase `C`.

`onclick` is just `click` in jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#resize').click(function() {
    $('.frame_wrap').addClass('test');
  })
});
```

```css
.test {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview_site">
  <div class="preview_wrap">
    <iframe class="frame_wrap" src="https://www.bdanzer.com"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="resize">Button</button>
```

Comment: Ahh yeah the captial C for class was messing me up a bit there. If I wanted to check for if statements like if it his this class then remove or if it doesn't have this class add. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Bdanzer jQuery has a `toggleClass` function that does just what you want. http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

There is not such function as `onclick` in `jquery`

It should be `click(function(){})` or `on('click', function(){})`. Also addclass should be `addClass`

Change to

```
$(document).ready(
  $('#resize').click(function() {
    $('.frame_wrap').addClass('test');
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use addClass() instead of addclass because it is case sensitive.